# How do i get the contents of html that currently displaying on web view?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How do i get the current displaying contents of html in web view(epub).
Is there any way to get the current displying contents (view port contents) instead displying all contents using following  `document.getElementById().innerHTML()`.

Is there any way to get webview displaying contents froma big html file.

Comment: Do you want to get the elements which display is 'block' at current view..??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the contents of a UIWebView you can use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.

Example:

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please read my question sir ..i need only the html contents that displying on webview not all html